# How to store date in Oracle DB without timezone using TypeORM

Tags: node.js, oracle, typeorm

I am using TypeORM and Oracle database for the back-end.

In my project, I don't want to store timezone values in the database. It is causing so many issues. is there any way to set the config to don't store timezone in DB?

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the oracle database?  Sounds like it should be DATE, which does not include timezone.

Comment: @EdStevens, Yes I am using date datatype. still, it's taking time zone

Comment: The data type DATE, by definition, does not include any information about time zone.